# Hide/Remove a tag after X seconds with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout

I am wondering how can I hide/remove a tag after a certain amount of time. Is there some built in thing or do I do use threading(if javascript can do this?)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You don't even need jQuery for the "5 seconds" part: JavaScript's built-in `setTimeout` function will do the trick.  Incorporating jQuery for the DOM manipulation, you get:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#the-tag-you-want-to-remove").remove();
}, 5000);
```

Here the `5000` represents 5000 milliseconds, or 5 seconds.  You can pass `setTimeout` an existing function or (as in this case) an anonymous function.

Comment: another thing to note is that you can pass it a string to evaluate, though i would discourage against this unless absolutely necessary

Comment: Also I always use the "window" prefix because you never know when somebody else (plugin etc) will create a func/var with the same name in scope that does something else

Comment: Its has helped me great job

Answer (score 9):

Try to use .delay() function

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 3):

```
window.setTimeout( hideTagFn, 5000);

function hideTagFn(){

   $('#someElementId').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is almost similar to the above answers but in this example you just have to copy as it is and paste it in your editor then it will work.

```
<hmtl>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.showupAfter8seconds').hide();
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.showupAfter8seconds').show();
  },8000);
});
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="showupAfter8seconds">
      <h1>I was hidden for 8 seconds</h1>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```